# flutter passing a function with parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I've an issue with a function that I pass as parameter. I dont understand why I've this error 'the parameter '' can't have a 'null' because of its type'

I made a function that Push a new screen in my statefull class (changeAuthScreen). And I call it and my widget function ButtonAuth (onPressed).
[image: the class where there's the error]

[image: the function that I use for call the class]

[image: where this function is called]

Comment: Can you inlcude code-snippet instead of code-image that will raise the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue raise because of null-safety aware. While the bool is final, you need to make it required like or  provide default value .

```dart
const AuthScreen({super.key, required this.newUser});
```

or

```dart
const AuthScreen({super.key, this.newUser = false});
```

Find more about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 1):

In line 17, you have to add the required keyword:

```dart
const AuthScreen({Key? key, required this.newUser}) : super(key);
```

This will fix the issue.